# Using Storybook v6 useArgs throws a TypeError

Tags: storybook

I'm trying to use the `useArgs()` hook to update args. Since `@storybook/client-api` is deprecated, I'm using the `@storybook/api` library instead. However, it throws a TypeError when I try to use it in a template:

```js
import { useArgs } from "@storybook/api";
import Button from "./Button";

export default {
  title: "Button",
  component: Button,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Button>;

const ToggleTemplate: ComponentStory<typeof Button> = (args) => {
  const [_, updateArgs] = useArgs();

  return <Button {...args} />;
};
export const Toggle: typeof Template = ToggleTemplate.bind({});

Toggle.args = {
  children: "Toggle me!",
  toggle: {
    toggleFunc: () => {},
    value: false,
  },
};
```

The above throws `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCurrentStoryData')`. When I comment out `useArgs()`, the error disappears. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `useArgs` from the wrong package. The `@storybook/api` is for creating an addon, not using it in a story ([Storybook Docs: Addon API](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/addons/addons-api)). For inside a story, install `@storybook/client-api` and change the import to `import { useArgs } from '@storybook/client-api';`

Comment: But `@storybook/client-api` is deprecated

Comment: Use `@storybook/preview-api` instead with storybook 7. See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/950df76ef306e85a280b98477e8ed41862281b38/code/deprecated/client-api/README.md#L2.